# iOS How to load a table after data is loaded?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

In my iOS Project I want to generate a table with data from a json file, the problem is that the table is created before the data is loaded!

How can I generate the table after the data is loaded?

Answer (score 4):

When the loading of the data is completed, call `[tableView reloadData]` **on the main thread.**

Comment: If i enter [tableView reloadData] it gives me an error and suggest [UITableView reloadData] but then it gives me a warning class method +reload data not found and if i execute the app it crashes when the function is called ! What should i do ?

Comment: @TimOch You should think instead of copy-pasting. Obviously, you have to substitute the actual variable name instead of `tableView`.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your viewDidLoad method, you get the data as an asynchronous process in the background.
2. When the data arrives, parse it out and populate your "model".
3. Once model is populated, use notification manager to send a notice to anyone interested in that fresh data.
4. Catch the notice in your tableview and call [self.tableView reloadData];

That's the gist of it.  Best of luck!